# Use the Same Learning Rate to Train All Models When Doing Experiments For A Deep Learning Paper?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, tensorflow, computer-vision

When writing a deep learning paper, I need to train several CNN models and compare their performances. They are from different architectures so different designs.

I'm wondering should I use the same learning rate for all models when training (I've made sure they all have the same batch size, same loss function, etc), or should I create a naive tuner and find the best learning rate for each of the model?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rule out that different architectures will benefit from different learning rates, so if you have the resources, you should give it a try.

Just make sure that you have a [decent optimizer](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/Nadam/) and that you have followed all the [standard rules](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/352036/6193) for learning DNNs.

Comment: Thank you! So if I have to use different learning rate for each one, do I need to indicate what I used for each one in the paper, or do you think I don't include such detailed information like the learning rate in my paper? Thank you again!

Comment: It doesn't hurt to add it. Maybe you provide an appendix for all the details.